# Pi Hole with web interface and wordpress on the same Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: wordpress, apache, raspberry-pi, raspbian

in my raspberry run pi hole with web int, i want to install also a wordpress site with local ip but when i try to install the component apache cannot start the server at the end of installation. How can i do to create a pvt site in local area with pi hole in the same RPi?
Thank you. 
ps below the error code if can be usefull :)

````
pi@PotatoServer:~ $ sudo apt install apache2 -y
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
I seguenti pacchetti sono stati installati automaticamente e non sono più richiesti:
  alsa-base gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-plugins-base liba52-0.7.4
  libaribb24-0 libbasicusageenvironment1 libcddb2 libdav1d3 libdvbpsi10
  libebml4v5 libgroupsock8 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0
  libixml10 liblirc-client0 liblivemedia64 libllvm8 libmatroska6v5
  libmicrodns0 libmpeg2-4 libopenmpt-modplug1 libplacebo7 libprotobuf-lite17
  libproxy-tools libresid-builder0c2a libsidplay2 libspatialaudio0
  libspeexdsp1 libupnp13 libusageenvironment3 libvlc-bin libvlc5 libvlccore9
  libxcb-xv0 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-2
  pimixer point-rpi vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt
  vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-output
  vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization xfconf
Usare "sudo apt autoremove" per rimuoverli.
Pacchetti suggeriti:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
I seguenti pacchetti NUOVI saranno installati:
  apache2
0 aggiornati, 1 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
È necessario scaricare 0 B/251 kB di archivi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno occupati 613 kB di spazio su disco.
Selezionato il pacchetto apache2 non precedentemente selezionato.
(Lettura del database... 159463 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Preparativi per estrarre .../apache2_2.4.38-3+deb10u3_armhf.deb...
Estrazione di apache2 (2.4.38-3+deb10u3)...
Configurazione di apache2 (2.4.38-3+deb10u3)...
Enabling module mpm_event.
Enabling module authz_core.
Enabling module authz_host.
Enabling module authn_core.
Enabling module auth_basic.
Enabling module access_compat.
Enabling module authn_file.
Enabling module authz_user.
Enabling module alias.
Enabling module dir.
Enabling module autoindex.
Enabling module env.
Enabling module mime.
Enabling module negotiation.
Enabling module setenvif.
Enabling module filter.
Enabling module deflate.
Enabling module status.
Enabling module reqtimeout.
Enabling conf charset.
Enabling conf localized-error-pages.
Enabling conf other-vhosts-access-log.
Enabling conf security.
Enabling conf serve-cgi-bin.
Enabling site 000-default.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service → /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache-htcacheclean.service → /lib/systemd/system/apache-htcacheclean.service.
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset:enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-03-09 02:08:51 CET; 22ms ago
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
  Process: 637 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: Action 'start' failed.
mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: The Apache error log may have more             information.
mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Elaborazione dei trigger per man-db (2.8.5-2)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per systemd (241-7~deb10u3+rpi1)...
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Pihole uses Lighttpd as its webserver which defaults to listening to listing on port 80.  Apache also listens on port 80 which is why you are getting the following error.

> mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: (98)Address already in
>   use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 mar 09
>   02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: (98)Address already in use:
>   AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 mar 09
>   02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: no listening sockets available,
>   shutting down mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]: AH00015:
>   Unable to open logs mar 09 02:08:51 PotatoServer apachectl[637]:
>   Action 'start' failed.

To resolve this you would need to change the port that either Apache or Lighttpd are listening on.  To change Apache's default port on raspbian:

```
nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

Change Listen 80 to something else like Listen 8080.  Then hit ctrl-x and y to close and save the file.  Now you also need to change the virtual host statement.  For the default installation you can do this by editing 000-default.conf.

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabld/000-default.conf
```

Change VirtualHost *:80 to VirtualHost *:8080.  Then close and save the file again.

Finally, start Apache.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```